# USDZ File Not Loading on iPhone 7

Tags: xcode, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

Our USDZ file won't load on iPhone 7 with iOS 12. It works fine on my iPhone X and iPad Pro, both running iOS 12 Beta.

We've tried creating this using the terminal commands and get the following warning although we don't believe this is the issue.

```
Warning: in CreateMaterialBindings at line 59 of /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/3DAssetTools/3DAssetTools-14207.2/external/ModelKit/extern/usd/pxr/usd/usdObj/translator.cpp -- OBJ mtl usemtl name has invalid name '15___Default', using default usemtl name: 'defaultShadeGroup0'
```

The screen on the iPhone 7 looks as such:

[image]

You can download the raw files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-xMJKky_xrBkPXizb6eVfkWUmbps55VO/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

> You can't see your 3D model because you're using very bad naming convention for file **`model2_$$usd_converter$$_.usdc`** inside `usdz` container. In macOS and iOS you have to avoid using **`$`** in file names, because ***dollar sign is a special character***.

Follow these two steps to unzip, rename and rezip your `usdz` file.

## First Step (unzip `mmtest.usdz` file)

> To unzip a `usdz` file in macOS Mojave use the following method:

- In Finder change the extension of `.usdz` file to `.zip`.
- Uncompress `.zip` file using `Archive_Utility.app` or `RAR_Extractor.app`.
- Open unzipped directory and change files' names.
- Make sure all textures are in `JPG` and/or `PNG` format.
- Make sure 3D normals of your `USDC` model ain't inverted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Second Step (recreate `usdz` again)

Make sure that Xcode 10.2 is installed.

> To convert a content of unzipped folder (binary `usdc` file and its textures) to `usdz` file format again, use the following command in `Terminal.app`:

```
cd ~/Desktop/mmtest/


xcrun usdz_converter Model.usdc Model.usdz 
-g SofaMesh
-color_map Diffuse.jpg
-roughness_map Roughness.png
-normal_map Normal.jpg
```

And here are a full list of options (type **`xcrun usdz_converter -h`** in Terminal):

```
-g groupName [groupNames ...]        Apply subsequent material properties to the named group(s).
-m materialName [materialNames ...]  Apply subsequent material properties to the named material(s).
-h                                   Display help.
-a                                   Generate a .usda intermediate file.  Default is .usdc.
-l                                   Leave the intermediate .usd file in the source folder.
-v                                   Verbose output.
-f                    filePath       Read commands from a file.
-texCoordSet          set            The name of the texturemap coordinate set to use if multiple exist (no quotes).
-opacity              o              Floating point value 0.0...1.0

-color_default        r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-normal_default       r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-emissive_default     r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-metallic_default     r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-roughness_default    r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-ao_default           r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0

-color_map            filePath
-normal_map           filePath
-emissive_map         filePath
-metallic_map         filePath
-roughness_map        filePath
-ao_map               filePath
```

Now model works perfectly.

[image]